# Pycharm error "Please specify different SDK"

Tags: pycharm, sdk

I get an error when I try to add or delete a new virtual environment to my project: "error please specify different sdk".
[list of project interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwDAg.png)
[error after trying to delete some interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NOSG.png)

I try to rename or delete existing virtual environments I get the same error when I save.
I don't want to delete jdk.table.xml (i don't reaaly understand all impact of this)

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me?
I use PyCharm 2022.2.3 (Community Edition)

Thank you.